Error 431 when running Web API template project
I installed the latest version of .Net 6.0.32
I am running the latest version of Visual Studio Community Edition Version 17.7.5
I created a new ASP.NET Core Web API project from the template with the following options:

I updated all the Nuget packages to the latest versions for .Net 6.
When I run the project without making any changes other than to update the Nuget packages, I get the following error when using Kestrel:
HTTP Error 431
If I use IIS Express, the project will run just fine.
I've tried this in several browsers and I get the same error in all of them.
I would like to be able to use Kestrel.  Has anyone else had this error and know how to fix it?

"I am running the latest version of Visual Studio" - No, you're not: v17.7 is out-of-date. We're on v17.10 now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes

HTTP 431 is Request Header Fields Too Large - which I assume means you have huge cookies or similar (possibly caused by storing (already bloated) access-tokens using some inefficient  encoding within ASP.NET Core's own encrypted cookies. You should fix that. All cookies combined for a single website should not exceed 4096 bytes.

Try this:

click F12
goto application
clear the cache


